# How to send a deque collection via flask in python

Tags: python, flask, deque

I am trying to send a deque collection filled with integers via Flask in a simple flask app.

the problem I am facing is that the deque is not serializable

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import collections


d=collections.deque(maxlen=10)


app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def index():
    for i in range(10):
        d.append(i)
    return jsonify(d)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the output error is

```
TypeError: Object of type deque is not JSON serializable
```

How can i serialize a deque collection to be sent via flask? taking into consideration that I need to undergo some mathimatical algorithms over the sent integers through this deque on another python server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python deque is similar to list (in many terms). The main difference I know between both, is that changing operations (such as `pop()`) are way more efficiant with deque.

So you don't you try to jsonify a list instead of a deque ?

Comment: I had the ability to send a list in a dictionary via flask and it worked. But according to my application I need to use a deque collection instead of list because of the deque properties (fast and special for append and pop). so is it possible to have a dictionary of deques?

Comment: I'm not 100% sur but I think you can't directly. But you don't need it to be a deque when you send it ? So why don't you convert it to a list and then re-convert it to a deque when you have to ?

Comment: its a choice also, but i want to know if its possible directly to send a deque, or its complicated. but thank you any way

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Custom Encoder, which knows how to turn a deque into JSON:

```
from json import JSONEncoder
from collections import deque

class DequeEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
       if isinstance(obj, deque):
          return list(obj)
       return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And use it like:

```
d = deque(("A", "B", "C"))
json.dumps(d, cls=DequeEncoder)
```